# Update DLL in production server in bin folder throw parse Error when application run

Tags: c#, asp.net, production

I m working on Asp.net Web Application I run the application on local and staging server working properly when I update dll in bin folder while when i go to upload on production server it throw Parser Error Exception

**Code**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TopNavigation.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.Modules.Masters.TopNavigation" %>
<%@ Register Src="../Other/Search_Box.ascx" TagName="Search_Box" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

**Error**
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service     this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SitefinityWebApp.Modules.Masters.TopNavigation'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  
Line 2:   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TopNavigation.ascx.cs"
        Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.Modules.Masters.TopNavigation" %>
Line 3:   <%@ Register Src="../Other/Search_Box.ascx" TagName="Search_Box" TagPrefix="uc1" %>


Source File: Modules/Masters/TopNavigation.aspx    Line: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: See Creating a Virtual Directory for Your Application for detailed instructions on creating a virtual directory for your application.

Solution 2: Your application’s Bin folder is missing or the application’s DLL file is missing. See Copying Your Application Files to a Production Server for detailed instructions.

Solution 3: You may have deployed to the web root folder, but have not changed some of the settings in the Web.config file. See Deploying to web root for detailed instructions.

In my case Solution 2 works, while deploying to server some DLL's from bin directory has not been uploaded to server successfully. I have re-upload all DLL's again and it works!!

Comment: Did u achieved the result?

Comment: yet not while i applied old dll of existing site then it will working fine